# BLE packet sent from Raspberry Pi does not contain UUID?

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatttool

I'm using temperature Sensor in my project which supports BLE, first I checked this sensor with android mobile with BeaconSet+ app it worked fine, later I tried to connect with Raspberry Pi it got connected, but problem is I can't able to read characteristic data from sensor, but I'm able to read it in android mobile, so I tried to capture and compare two packets the difference I noted is [Bluetooth packet from raspberry Pi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGyCS.png) only contains handle it does not contain UUID but packets from [Bluetooth Packet from Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLR2i.png) contains both handle and UUID, is this the reason that I'm not getting my data with Raspberrry Pi.

Tools I used are gatttool and bluetoothctl and version of bluez is 5.55.